# Ruy - How to include an .rb file that's just a huge array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to include a stand-alone file that is simply something like:

`bad_stuff = ['one', 'two', 'etc']`

I want to separate it that I can just update that file and have methods read it.

Is there any way to do this easily without using a class/method?

A method in a utility class, which has many other methods.

```
def self.get_banned_domains
    banned_domains = ['whatever.com']
    return banned_domains
end
```

Comment: Define _huge_. Hundreds? Thousands? Millions? The bigger the list is the more like it might be that storing the list in a database and using SQL operations might be more efficient than working on a plain array in memory.

Comment: [`Kernel#load`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Kernel.html#method-i-load) might be an option but a database (possibly even an SQLite database) might be a better idea.

Answer (score 3):

This type of thing is more usually using a serialization format such as JSON or YAML. This allows the file to be hand-edited and you load it into a Ruby array by simply `JSON.parse(File.read("/path.json"))` or `YAML.load(File.read("/path.yml"))`

If you wanted to put it in a Ruby file, though, you can use a constant:

```
# path.rb
MY_LIST = [1,2,3]

# other_file.rb
require 'path.rb'
puts MY_LIST.length # => 3
```

Comment: Yeah I just want to avoid having to parse a huge list from json every time I need to do a check and at the same time I don't want the list to be loaded until it's needed. I guess I can't have it both ways : (

Comment: Could you not [memoize it](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/ruby-memoization-and-alternative)? You could keep it in JSON/YAML and just load it if there's a request to begin with. Then it'll stay in memory until you need it again.

Comment: @user3096851: Ruby is a much more complex language than JSON, so parsing it is much more expensive than JSON. So, why are you okay in parsing a huge list from Ruby but not from JSON?

Comment: @user3096851 you could have it both ways. Load the file once when the app starts, and assign it to a constant

Answer (score 0):

Try `require 'filename'`. It will act like that code is in your file, then.

*Note: I am curious though, why you don't want to use a utility class with methods. That would have been my approach.*

Comment: Sorry, I think my brain skipped. At first I was using 'include', then I thought about a helper, or an initializer, or etc. It's late and my brain is fried. Thanks.

Comment: I am glad to have helped. There is also the chance you want to define a global variable like this as such with $. Like `$bad_stuff = ...` https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-and-in-Ruby-1